# Problem sendind data with socket.io and Flask

Tags: flask, socket.io

Good morning,

I'm unable to pass data from app.py to the results.html page using Flask and Socket.IO. I've enabled the console, but there are no errors, and the variables are being printed in the terminal. Do you have any idea what I can do?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import threading
import time
from queue import Queue
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

# Variabile globale per memorizzare i dati estratti
extracted_data_queue = Queue()

@app.route('/')
def login():
    return render_template('ChooseDate.html')

@app.route('/scegli', methods=['POST'])
def start_scraping():
    selected_month = request.form.get('month')
    threading.Thread(target=scrape_data, args=(selected_month,)).start()
    return render_template('results2.html')

def scrape_data(selected_month):
    numbers = []
    start_number = int(selected_month)
    end_number = start_number + 9  
    
    for i in range(start_number, end_number):
        time.sleep(1)
        numbers.append(i)
        socketio.emit('data_update', {'data': numbers}, namespace='/')
        print('Sending data:', numbers)
        extracted_data_queue.put(numbers)

@app.route('/get_data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    data = extracted_data_queue.get()
    return jsonify(data=data)

@app.after_request
def add_cache_control(response):
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0'
    return response

port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port,debug=True)
```

an the html code of resulst2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Risultati</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style media="screen">
        /* Stili CSS qui */
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.3.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var socket = io.connect();

            socket.on('data_update', function(msg) {
                var data = msg.data;
                console.log('Received data:', data);
                $('#data-container').empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $('#data-container').append('<p>' + data[i] + '</p>');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Fenster nicht Schliessen!</h1>
        <div id="data-container"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To pass the information trough the app.py and the website.